# Find out max dates of all users in same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table data with multiple imei. I want to find out all max(dates) of all imei. 
I am writing this query:

```
SELECT * 
from data 
where gpsdatetime=(
        select max(gpsdatetime) 
        from data) 
    AND imei in("+imei_string+");
```

But this fetches all the data of selected imei and then selects only one max date from all the data.

I want to find out all max(dates) of all imei.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT imei, MAX(gpsdatetime)
FROM data
GROUP BY imei
```

This query makes use of the [GROUP BY clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d70a8/1).

If you want all imei rows (even duplicates) then use the following query:

```
SELECT a.imei, b.gpsdatetime
FROM data a
JOIN (
  SELECT imei, MAX(gpsdatetime) as gpsdatetime
  FROM data
  GROUP BY imei
) b
ON a.imei = b.imei
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d70a8/4).

Comment: This query will give you all `imei` numbers and those numbers will be unique in the resulting record set. Against each `imei` number you have have its corresponding MAX date.

Comment: I want max(date) of all imei. I mean if I have 2 imei in my table then records will be two

Comment: For that, I have added second query (and its demo) in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this
`SELECT * From data D`
`where gpsdatetime in (select max(gpsdatetime) from Data group by imei)`
`AND imei in("+imei_string+");`